# проблема в коде Python

Tags: python, текст

Проблема в том что не получается выводить следующе число после введенного

```
f3 = open("log32.txt", "r")
lst3 = f3.readlines()
a = lst3


while True: 
    y = int(input("a"))

for t in a:
        if t == y:
                print(lst3[i:len(lst3+1):1])
```

Comment: пример списка 5
345
44
5342
4
2
423
64
23
45
25
2
52
5
235
235

Comment: Кажется, следует поместить цикл for внутрь цикла while. Добавьте табуляцию

Comment: Добавить пример списка в вопрос можно используя кнопку "Править" под вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом коде не совсем есть смысл:

```
while True:
y = int(input("a"))
```

Надо написать без цикла, либо ограничить его итерации.
Можно пройтись по данным и foreach и сконвертировать числа.

```
f3 = open("log32.txt", "r")
lst3 = f3.readlines()
a = lst3


y = int(input("a"))



for t in a:
    if int(t) == y:
        print(t)
```

Вот как я проверил одно число на равенство.
В log32.txt ,были числа от 1 до 10 в строчку.

Comment: спасибо но как мне вывести следующие число по списку

Comment: Делайте ввод внутри цикла for. Либо выведите все в список и сравните ваш ввод со списком по очереди

Answer (score 1):

`y` - число. `t` - строка. Число никогда не будет равно строке. Кроме того, в зависимости от того, как записаны числа в файле (в одну строку или по одному на строчку), итерация в цикле может идти по отдельным числам или же возьмутся сразу все.